# How to see all recent directories?

Tags: dired, recentf

Linux Mint 20
Emacs 27

package: dired, diredp (https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dired%2b.el)

1. Jump to bookmark. Input Temp
   [image]
2. Press ENTER. As result open folder **MyFolder**
   [image]
3. Press ENTER. As result open folder **MySubfolder_1**
   [image]
4. `M-x diredp-dired-recent-dirs`

[image]

1.Why in buffer *Recently Visited Directories* not show recently visited folders?

```
MyFolder
MySubfolder_1
```

2. Is it possible to show recent visited directories in the minibuffer?

Answer (score 2):

[Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) just uses your `recentf-list` of files and directories. It is library `recentf.el` that controls what file and dir names to record there.

For that, library `recentf.el` provides several user options, which filter out certain file and dir names, etc.  That's no doubt what you're running into.

---

Your second question isn't clear to me (and you really should pose only one question per question). Perhaps you're asking how you can echo the list of recent directories to the echo area (same space as the minibuffer, but for output, not input).

For that, you can use this command:

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (message "Recent dirs: %S" (diredp-recent-dirs nil)))
```

(If you want a different sort order, let-bind variable `diredp-default-sort-arbitrary-function` to a function that sorts the way you want.)